# Under what conditions is a JSESSIONID created?

Tags: java, jsessionid

When / what are the conditions when a `JSESSIONID` is created?

Is it per a domain? For instance, if I have a Tomcat app server, and I deploy multiple web applications, will a different `JSESSIONID` be created per context (web application), or is it shared across web applications as long as they are the same domain?

Answer (score 376, accepted):

JSESSIONID cookie is created/sent when session is created. Session is created when your code calls `request.getSession()` or `request.getSession(true)` for the first time. If you just want to get the session, but not create it if it doesn't exist, use `request.getSession(false)` -- this will return you a session or `null`. In this case, new session is not created, and JSESSIONID cookie is not sent. (This also means that **session isn't necessarily created on first request**... you and your code are in control *when* the session is created)

Sessions are per-context:

> SRV.7.3 Session Scope
>
> HttpSession objects must be scoped at
>   the application (or servlet context)
>   level. The underlying mechanism, such
>   as the cookie used to establish the
>   session, can be the same for different
>   contexts, but the object referenced,
>   including the attributes in that
>   object, must never be shared between
>   contexts by the container.

([Servlet 2.4 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr154/index.html))

Update: Every call to JSP page implicitly creates a new session if there is no session yet. This can be turned off with the `session='false'` page directive, in which case session variable is not available on JSP page at all.

Comment: cant a session be created w/o an explicit call to getSession?

in regards to "must never be shared between contexts by the container", websphere has an option to share sessions, which is the motivation for the question :)

Comment: Not if you use just Servlet API. There may be server-specific extensions (like Websphere's session sharing as you point out) though.

Comment: I believe your context.xml file can control the automatic session creation if your <Context> tag contains a cookies attribute, e.g.

<Context cookies="false">

Comment: Right now im getting many hits on my filter to create session and seems like its only after the second hit (not a second page refresh) its being created, this called my attention " session isn't necessarily created on first request.." is it related? could you give an example why this is not necessarily created at first request? Thanks!

Comment: @jpganz18: If you simply call `request.getSession()` or `request.getSession(true)`, then you get either existing or new session. However if your code calls `request.getSession(false)`, then you get either existing session or null, if no session exists.

Comment: 1)  `HttpSession` objects must be scoped at the application level. 2) session object is created for every browser connection to tomcat. Am unable to relate these two points.

Answer (score 61):

Here is some information about one more source of the `JSESSIONID` cookie:

I was just debugging some Java code that runs on a tomcat server. I was not calling `request.getSession()` explicitly anywhere in my code but I noticed that a `JSESSIONID` cookie was still being set.

I finally took a look at the generated Java code corresponding to a JSP in the work directory under Tomcat.

It appears that, whether you like it or not, if you invoke a JSP from a servlet, `JSESSIONID` will get created!

Added: I just found that by adding the following JSP directive:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

you can disable the setting of `JSESSIONID` by a JSP.

Comment: In other words: the default value for the page session attribute is "true". Which might be unexpected in some (many?) cases.

Comment: I'm also on tomcat, and I do not use jsp at all, but the session cookie is created anyway. Any idea how to prevent it in this situation?

Answer (score 31):

CORRECTION: Please vote for Peter Štibraný's answer - it is more correct and complete!

A "JSESSIONID" is the unique id of the http session - [see the javadoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). There, you'll find the following sentence

> Session information is scoped only to the current web application (ServletContext), so information stored in one context will not be directly visible in another.

So when you first hit a site, a new session is created and bound to the SevletContext. If you deploy multiple applications, the session is not shared.

You can also invalidate the current session and therefore create a new one. e.g. when switching from http to https (after login), it is a very good idea, to create a new session.

Hope, this answers your question.

Comment: Clear explanation of session scope.

Comment: @Mo the link is broken

Answer (score 9):

Beware if your page is including other .jsp or .jspf (fragment)! If you don't set

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

on them as well, the parent page will end up starting a new session and setting the JSESSIONID cookie.

For .jspf pages in particular, this happens if you configured your web.xml with such a snippet:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

in order to enable scriptlets inside them.

Comment: Do you mean set page session=false in all the fragments included (.jsp and .jspf) and not include it in the main jsp that include the rest of snippets?

Answer (score 2):

For links generated in a JSP with custom tags, I had to use

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

in the JSP

AND

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

in the Struts action