# can you explain the purpose of jsession id in portlet

Tags: java

can you explain the purpose of jsession id in portlet

Comment: This page is not really a duplicate but good enough to know what a JSessionID is for, PLEASE, search first before you ask a question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created

Answer (score 1):

[JSR-168 Java Portlet Specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr168/index.html) has a chapter on sessions. It is basically the same as in other java web applications. It is used to identify session specific data as logged in user, its shoppingcart contents etc.