# Servlet: weird cookie string

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, request, session-cookies

I'm running my servlet on Tomcat 7. When retrieving cookies with the request.getCookies(); the values returned are weird strings "8267663C31A2F33C16B7C0D864874DC4"

Can anyone tell me what this is?

Output from 2 text form data:

> 8267663C31A2F33C16B7C0D864874DC4
>
> test
>
> test
>
> 8267663C31A2F33C16B7C0D864874DC4

Thanks,

Nguyen

Answer (score 5):

That looks very much like a session ID. Is the name of that cookie "JSESSIONID" ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably looks like a `jsessionid` used for [associating a given user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created) with a servlet session on the server side.