# is there any formula on server to generate JSESSIONID?

Tags: java, web-services, jsp

I just want to know how any server generates the JSESSION id is it unique or if server restarted then it will generate the same session id that was previously generated by server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not standard. Every app server might have their own strategy. It is supposed to be unique. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

you will get answer of Under what conditions is a JSESSIONID created?

here [Under what conditions is a JSESSIONID created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created)

Comment: thanks @Hemand but I want to know what is formula of session id?