# JSessionID not changing after user logs out - Is this a security issue?

Tags: java, security, servlets, weblogic

During some debugging of our WebLogic application, I've noticed that the JSESSIONID doesn't change after the user logs out.

I'm trying to understand if this is something I need to be concerned with.

This application is one of two applications running within a WebLogic instance, and I notice that they both share the same JSESSIONID.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/598923/59015) makes reference to the following:

> SRV.7.3 Session Scope
>
> HttpSession objects must be scoped at the application (or servlet
>   context) level. The underlying mechanism, such as the cookie used to
>   establish the session, can be the same for different contexts, but the
>   object referenced, including the attributes in that object, must never
>   be shared between contexts by the container.

This suggests that ultimately it's up to WegLogic to choose how to manage these JSESSIONID values, and I should not try to interpret meaning from the change in value (or lack thereof).

Additionally, I've wired up an `HttpSessionListener` on the application, and I see the `sessionDestroyed` method get invoked.

Given these two elements, it seems safe to me that the JSESSIONID is not changing.  However, this is different behaviour from what I'm used to, so would like to verify my assumptions.

Is it a security concern that the JSESSIONID doesn't change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be a huge security concern, since all the data that was actually associated with that session is discarded.  The `JSESSIONID` is just a key to that (now nonexistent) data.

However, if you want the `JSESSIONID` to change on each logout/login, you could just implement your logout functionality such that it explicitly deletes the `JSESSIONID` cookie when the user logs out.  Then the server will allocate them a brand new session/id on their next request.

Of course, as noted in the documentation, if you have multiple contexts that all happen to be relying on the single `JSESSIONID` cookie, then deleting it from one will essentially delete it from all, effectively logging the user out of every context on your server.  Although in practice, it's not hugely common to have multiple user-facing contexts, each with its own login/session state.