# Handle CROS Domain in Codeigniter -- Session Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my `php` files on a `server` where i can access them using `ajax` from my `mobile app`.
I used `Code-Igniter` from my mobile i sent first request in which it `authenticates` a user and save all `sessions` but when i sent next `request` in which `authentication` is required in that it gets nothing i think `session` destroyed. So how i can handle this in `CodeIgniter` previously i used custom style simple `php` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your application `server` side on every `request` you `session starts`.
So its batter that first time you capture the `SESSION Token` and when you make next `request` that `session token` pass along with other `parameters`. All other `session management` is the responsibility of servers.

Detail Source Below

1. [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172124/2208432)
2. [Other Ways](http://www.rightscale.com/blog/cloud-management-best-practices/best-practices-managing-web-application-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in .htaccess in your CI folder equal folder with CI index.php

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: I used these in config/config.php
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');`

and my requests are reach properly

Comment: When i added those lines that you mentioned in answer it give me this error in console
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked`

Comment: i don't have file at that position so i just make new and add above lines in that

Comment: do u place the mean .htaccess file in the same directory of CI index.php file?

Comment: yes in folder where index.php.
But i have problem with saving seesion. Not accessing php files bcz i can access those files by adding this `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');` in php file so it can accessable from different domains

Comment: Yups that way work properly too because I use it before create .htaccess file. I don't know whats wrong eith this problem but it run in my server.

Comment: hmm but I send first request with email it process and validate user and set them into session. But when i send another request for getting some data from table it fails to authenticates (i think empty session it found) and return 'first sign in' that is display message on failed.