# How use @Ressource SessionContext right?

Tags: ejb, jaas

I need a bean for inject `@Ressource SessionContext ctx` with JAAS.
With the SessionContext can I check the user rights about `ctx.isCallerInRole("ROLE");`

But what is the right Bean declaration?
@Statful? @Stateless? and @SessionScope?
I need a instance for every User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the SessionContext can I check the user rights about ctx.isCallerInRole("ROLE")?

Yes you can.

> But what is the right Bean declaration? @Statful? @Stateless? and @SessionScope?

There is no `@SessionScope` for EJB. You can inject `SessionContext` both in `@Statful/@Stateless` bean. It depends on what you need. Usually User instance has to live as long as the session lives. EJB doesn't have session-scoped beans, so for that purpes it is often mixed with CDI (read more here [CDI + EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684112/how-do-cdi-and-ejb-compare-interact)) or other session-scoped beans like [Managed beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girch.html).

Comment: How do I guarantee that for each user the correct SessionContext is called up?

Comment: This is guaranteed by Java EE spec. For more information about sessions read about web server session management. This post might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960131/authentication-authorization-and-session-management-in-traditional-web-apps-and

Comment: My problem was, a user have the SessionContext from a other user. But now I think, It was a Context problem with the CDI Producer. Thank you.