# Proof for concept that JSession Id created by Browser or Server

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat, jsessionid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Under what conditions is a JSESSIONID created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created)

**Who creates JSession Id for a session : Browser or Server ?**
As per the following link : 
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?77388-who-creates-the-session-id-client-or-server
the server is responsible for the same. Could anyone please provide some POC (Proof Of Concept) for the same ? (Eg : A code snippet for some class creating JSession ID)