# Grails without session

Tags: grails, jsessionid

I noticed that grails applications, as most other java based web applications, always creates a session, even when it is not used.

Is it possible to set the JSESSIONID cookie only when needed, eg. when someone tries to log in?

Comment: why would you need to worry about that?

Comment: two reasons: 1) if you create a session, a cookie will be set. If I interpret the new "European Cookie Law" the right way, you have to ask you visitors for alloance before you set a cookie. 2) a session uses resources. If I don't need the session, why should I create one? And if I expose a REST interface and the client ignores the cookies, each request will create a new session :-(

Comment: You should do some more research: Consent not necessary
Any cookie that, were it not for its presence, the website would cease to be usable, for example a session cookie that maintains the contents of a customer’s basket through the checkout process. That said, if you were to use this same cookie to track customer behaviour without asking them first, then this would require consent. http://www.enchiladadigital.com/services/cookie-audits/eu-cookie-law-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: what about my second reason?

Comment: Regarding research - taken from your link: `Well that’s all a little ambiguous isn’t it?

Quite frankly, yes.` And that's why it makes sense to avoid cookies at all if you don't need them...

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created) discussion might help
and [this](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-1977) JIRA too.
============================================================================
net net, this directive should work on your external facing pages where you want to avoid creating a session <%@ page session="false" %>. Haven't tried it myself though

Comment: Great! please copy and paste this as answer so that I can award you the bounty if it works... I will test it in jsut a moment and ocmment on it...

Comment: Yeah! It works - great! Just addidn the page directive does the trick :-)

Comment: @uchamp What about a situation where you aren't rendering a GSP, but instead rendering XML/JSON output?

Comment: @aasukisuki, no clue.

Comment: @aasukisuki I guess in this situation you should start about using a gsp to render you XML/JSON ;-) I just wonder if a `render view:'page_session_false.gsp'; render myModel as JSON` would work as workaround...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generation of a session cookie can be disabled by adding the following page directive:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of grails was being used above, but I was running into a similar issue in a large application. My application was split between UI/gsp and other Controllers that served pure json/xml without a view. The UI portion was supposed to be the only part that used sessions, but the services were also returning JSessionId.

Because the application was large, in order to troubleshoot, I created new applications with grails 1.3.7 and 2.2.1, with a basic controller:

```
class FooController {
    static defaultAction = "lookatme"
    def lookatme = {render(view:'lookatme')}
    def hallo = {render(text:"<xml>some xml</xml>",contentType:"text/xml",encoding:"UTF-8")}
    def somestate = {session.foo = "bar"; render(text:"<xml>some xml</xml>",contentType:"text/xml",encoding:"UTF-8")}
}
```

When I run this on tomcat, neither `lookatme` or `hallo` returns a JSessionId. The action `somestate` does. After going back through our code, we found places (some filters, for example) that were attempting to access session when they shouldn't.

If your code is returning a session via JSessionId cookies, and you don't think it should, ensure there is no code used within that action (or filters) which access `session` (or `flash`?).