# How is a session being created before my Spring interceptor is reached?

Tags: java, spring, session, jakarta-ee, interceptor

1. Client device clears all cookies (so, no `JSESSIONID` cookie exists on the client).
2. Client makes a request to Spring controller.
3. Spring Interceptor intercepts the request.

In the very first line of the `preHandle()` method of the Spring interceptor, I log the value of `request.getRequestedSessionId()` and the logs show a value for this, which should mean that a `JSESSIONID` was, in fact, received from the client.  However, my Fiddler logs show that no `JSESSIONID` was sent in the request.

In addition, `request.getSession(false).getId()` returns that same `JSESSIONID`.

So, how/when/why were the session and `JSESSIONID` created before the interceptor is even reached?  I would expect `request.getRequestedSessionId()` to be null if no `JSESSIONID` cookie was sent by the client.

And how do I prevent sessions from being created "on the fly" like this?

If it matters, the resource being requested is implemented like this:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
   .
   .
   .
   @RequestMapping(value = { "/controller/index.do" })
   public final ModelAndView login(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
      .
      .
      .
```

**EDIT -** As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/598923/1245897), I unserstand that every call to JSP page implicitly creates new session if there is no session yet.  But would this happen before the interceptor is reached?

**EDIT2 -** The interceptor is an instance of `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter`

Comment: Are you using JSPs on the client ?

Comment: @happybuddha good point, see my edit please.

Comment: Do you want to add details on what interceptors are being used ?

Comment: Try a [servlet filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) instead of a Spring `interceptor`. The session is established prior to your interceptor by the Java EE container.

Comment: @happybuddha The interceptor is an instance of `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter`

Comment: @GriffeyDog would the code in the servlet filter run BEFORE the Java EE container establishes the session?

Comment: @GriffeyDog if you can post an answer that explains how to use a servlet filter to prevent a session from being created on the fly BEFORE the request reaches the interceptor, I will graciously accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a servlet filter. Something like this (untested):

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class MyFilter implements Filter {
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
      ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;         
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
    if (session == null) {
      // no session has been established yet      
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, resp); 
  }

  public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
}
```

Then, in your `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>mypackage.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> <!-- or whatever specific URL mappings you need -->
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think I may be able to use a servlet filter to detect when sessions are getting created on the fly.