# Extract JSESSIONID in REST after login

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, wildfly-8, jsessionid

I'm working on system which will allow users to create workspaces.After workspace creation user may login by providing username, password and workspace. 
And i need jsessionid generated after login to create connection between workspace and jsessionid.

Login goes thru REST.

```
    @POST
    @Path("login")
    @Produces(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF_8)
    public JsonObject login(LoginCredentials loginCredentials) throws UnAuthorizedException {
        //login logic
    }
```

I also have interceptor implementing ContainerResponseFilter, WriterInterceptor.

```
@Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext context)throws IOException {
        //...
    }
```

how can i get generated jsessionid (which i see in response header)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a http request object you can get hold of the associated session. Once you've got the session you can get its id

`request.getSession(true).getId()`

Passing `true` to `getSession` causes a new session to be created if one does not already exist.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've got the sessionid in login function from @Context HttpServletRequest request. request.getSession(false).getId().

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Jersey for the REST services, You can use e.g.

```
@Context HttpServletRequest request
```

in your service method signatures in order to access the response headers.
Take a look at 
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2742
and 
[Under what conditions is a JSESSIONID created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created) (this one is about JSessionID)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've used your and @DaveHowes tips to come up with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your interceptor you can get a request coming to your service and extract Headers or anything you put in the Request (so your JSESSIONID as well):

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) message
            .getExchange().getInMessage()
            .get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);
```

Comment: why to put jsession-id in the request?