# HtmlAgilityPack The parsed value differ

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse a web document. Using HtmlAgilityPack (C#)
That is exactly what looking for href value of a tag.

I'm parsing the [http://www.ntis.go.kr/ThRndGateList.do](http://www.ntis.go.kr/ThRndGateList.do.)

Although successful parse, the value is slightly different.
I do not know why.

The actual value of the web is as follows:

[image]

The value obtained through the Htmlagilitypack are as follows:

[image]

As you can see, this strange starting with "jsessionid" value in the href value is obtained. What reason?

Thank you for regards.

Comment: Can you please copy paste html and parsing results as text? I cannot see anything from these pictures

Comment: Could it be, that you are logged in to this Website in your browser?

Comment: The actual value : /ThRndGateView.do?searchType=&idx=211166&pageNumber=1&searchWord=

Comment: Get value : /ThRndGateView.do;jsessionid=joAOc6x4o7FZOw6TxF8eH5SjQOja0jX7V369TiM7MINx5hgQOg6wfoWLM1GjER90.ns10was_servlet_engine6?searchType=&amp;idx=211166&amp;pageNumber=1&amp;searchWord=  This will add more value, like this one.

Comment: @ClaudioP Yes. Sign in to Chrome is currently being used.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because in your browser (in your case Chrome) you are logged in. If you make the request via **HtmlAgilityPack** you are like a freshly open browser:

- Not logged in
- Never on this page before

The Webapplication your trying to use generates a `JSESSIONID` when someone opens the page for the first time and this id is transfered via the URL.

This question could help you to understand the technology behind the webapplication: [Under what conditions is a JSESSIONID created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created)