# jsessionid is saved and used even after reboot\re-installation of the service

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, sessionid, jsessionid

I have a Tomcat 7 web server.
After login to it I can see under Cookies that there is jsessionid which, from what I have read is saving the id of the session instance between the user and the web server.

But the thing I cannot understand is that after I login and I stay in the browser.
I can stop the server, even un install it from the system and re-install it. 
and then after I restart it I can continue navigating in the website without needing to enter credentials or anything like that, as if nothing happened in the background - I just can move on with the same jesssionId.

So basically I will divide my question into sub-question so it will be easier to answer:
1. How is it even possible that after stopping the service  or even un install it it can still happen?
2. How excatly is the jesessionID created? I mean is it possible that it is **the same jsession** id? 
3.When exactly does the jsessionID is being created?
4. Is it possible to change this behavior and "invalidate" the session so the user will have to re-enter his credentials?
5. Following question #4, what is common in most of the services? demand to login again or to enable the use of the old session id ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're on a higher version than Tomcat 6 you can go kill the session in the manager application.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? when do I do that? how do I do that programmaticaly  when the server is down? etc.
Any idea about the rest of the questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1. Tomcat's [session Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html) will serialize session data and save it to a file to persist it across restarts. You can [disable](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Disable_Session_Persistence) this.
2. Tomcat's [SessionId Generator](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/sessionidgenerator.html) determines the exact way the id is created.
3. Here a good answer for when session ids are created: [Under what conditions is a JSESSIONID created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created)
4. If your goal is to invalidate sessions after a Tomcat restart, you can do this by disabling session persistence.
5. Typically a user would want to be considered "logged in" until they click a "log out" link or button in your application. You can also adjust the session expiration time if you want the session to expire after a period of inactivity. How exactly this should work is up to you and depends on your application's use cases.