# cookies giving unusual values along with set values in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cookies

I have set cookies in a servlet class and read those cookies values in another servlet class. In another servlet class along with the set cookies values, I am getting some unusual values.

My Home.java servlet class results set ::
first result

```
Hello JSESSIONID, Hello A502A7144AE035ED9B1A2549F5C7B74B
Hello first_name, Hello RACHEL
Hello last_name, Hello KIM
```

second result

```
Hello JSESSIONID, Hello A502A7144AE035ED9B1A2549F5C7B74B
Hello first_name, Hello CAIRO
Hello last_name, Hello SENGAL
```

in both the results I am getting the set cookies values and names but along with them I am getting `JSESSIONID` and `A502A7144AE035ED9B1A2549F5C7B74B`. I can't understand from where do these cookies values are appearing? How can I remove this? Why are these values appearing?

My code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Authenticate
 */
@WebServlet("/Authenticate")
public class Authenticate extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Authenticate() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try
        {
            // Set response content type
            response.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
            String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
            String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");

            out.print("Welcome "+ firstname); 

            // Create cookies for first and last names.      
              Cookie f_name = new Cookie("first_name", firstname);
              Cookie l_name = new Cookie("last_name", lastname);

           // Add both the cookies in the response header.
              response.addCookie( f_name );
              response.addCookie( l_name );

            //creating submit button  
              out.print("<form action='Home' method='post' >");  
              out.print("<input type='submit' value='cookie click' />");  
              out.print("</form>");  

              out.close(); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("exception occured");
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Code for Home servlet

```
@WebServlet("/Home")
public class Home extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Home() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {

            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            Cookie ck[] = request.getCookies();
            if (ck != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ck.length; i++) {
                    out.print("Hello " + ck[i].getName() + ",  ");
                    out.print("Hello " + ck[i].getValue());
                    out.print("<br />");
                }
            }
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created) might help.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. There it is written to make session value false in page directive `<%@ page session="false" %>` jsp page. But here I am in servlet page, how can I make this tag false from servlet code. Please make me clarify.

Comment: Why do you care about the session cookie?  It is a fundamental part of the servlet specification.  Turning off something you don't understand and haven't researched makes no sense.