# Scope of session object

Tags: java, session, servlets, jsessionid, servlet-container

1)

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/598923/3317808),

> `HttpSession` objects must be scoped at the application (or servlet context) level, where context is,
>
> `ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();`

2)

`HttpSession` object is created per browser session, in tomcat memory.

### -----------------------------------------------------------------

Am unable to relate above two points.

An application is collection of different servlets. A servlet spawn a thread per connection from every browser. Every jsp/servlet points to a version of session object that the browser points to.

---

How can a session object that is created per browser gets scoped at web application level?

Answer (score -1):

Session(or session id) is generated at server and transfer to browser through cookie or URL rewriting(when cookie is banned in browser).

In general, a session id is generated while user access the website. And after logging in, the server will change the session id for safety issues.

Session expired when:

(1)call session.invalidate()

(2)timeout configuration:

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>xxx</session-timeout>
<session-config>
```

(3)Server restart(while the sessionid is saved in local cache)