# Java Web, sessions are being set automatically

Tags: java, session, servlets, jsessionid

I'm trying to create a login filter in my java web project. The problem is, when i call request.getSession(false), the session object returned is not null, in other words, the session is active. But I'm sure I didn't call getSession() in any other place of my code.
Even if I delete this filter, it doesnt work. If I open my browser dev tools, in network tab, it shows me a jsessionid set. It's session being set automatically?

Comment: The session would normally be created automatically. Particularly if the client is accessing a dynamic resource like a servlet or a jsp.

Comment: @ernest_k So, how I am able to make a login filter if a session is always opened?

Comment: A session does not imply login

Comment: But how I am able to make sure it's a login session?

Comment: you get to decide and implement that, maybe storing data in the session...

Comment: Are you using JSP pages?

Comment: Yeah, i'm using JSP

Comment: What's the point to have a HttpSession class/api if i have to implement everything by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to track a "logged in user", then I think what you are looking for is to track it using the HttpSession, like this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("loggedInUser", userObject);
```

Ypu can retrieve it from the session whenever you need it with:

```
Object loggedInUser = session.getAttribute("loggedInUser");
```

And later, when the user needs to "log out", clear the stored user from the session:

```
session.removeAttribute("loggedInUser");
```

To answer your question in the comments `What's the point to have a HttpSession class/api if i have to implement everything by myself?`: a [`HttpSession`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) represents a conversation with a specific client, so that subsequent requests from the same client can be identified and processed properly. It does not represent at all a "logged in user", that is a specific requirement from the domain - not all services require authentication.

Finally, if you need more details of when a JSESSIONID cookie is created, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created).