# Whether cookie must use with session?

Tags: http, session, cookies

We know http's cookie and session.
But I still have two questions:

Whether cookie must use with session?

if Client user do not login, the Server will not create session, right?

Answer (score 0):

When the client login you should create set new cookies on the session based on the strategy you wish to mange it, for example session-cookies erase once the tab is closed.
"if Client user do not login, the Server will not create session, right?"  - It depends on your server, some servers creates cookies explicitly upon request.

Comment: Could you explain more about `some servers creates cookies explicitly upon request`?

Comment: Very good explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created